# oracle group by get a group at a time

Tags: oracle, perl

My Data looks like this

```
 1. Fname    Lastname   DOB       ADDR   SEX   SSN 
 2. Sanal    Pillai    12/11/85   Pune   M     - 
 3. Sunil    Pillai    05/11/80   Pune   M     123456 
 4. Anju     Pillai    12/11/85   Pune   F     345679 
 5. Arachana Pillai    05/11/80   Pune   M
```

-

Now is I do a group by on DOB I would get the data arranged accordingly

```
select fname,lastname,dob,addr,sex,ssn from data group by dob(..rest of the columns..) having count(dob) > 1
```

But what I would like to know is, is it possible to get a group at a time, ie

```
 1. Sanal    Pillai    12/11/85   Pune   M     -
 2. Anju     Pillai    12/11/85   Pune   F     345679
```

and then the rest two rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [RANK](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions141.htm#SQLRF00690) or [DENSE_RANK](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions052.htm#SQLRF00633) analytic functions to assign grouping ID's and order by that:

```
with t1 as (
  select data.*, dense_rank() over (order by dob) grp from data
)
select t1.* from t1 order by grp;
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi i think you may not know the exact functionality of group by clause. Below i have posted few lines for your understanding.

> The Oracle GROUP BY clause is used in a SELECT statement to collect
>   data across multiple records and group the results by one or more
>   columns.

**Syntax:**

```
SELECT col1, col2, ... coln, 
       aggregate_function (column_name)
FROM tables
WHERE conditions
GROUP BY col1, col2, ... coln;
```

The column_names what and all you mentioned in select clause you should also mention in after group by keyword. 
As per above syntax and your Question The required output query is:

```
select fname,lastname,dob,addr,sex,sum(ssn) as ssn from data group by fname,lastname,dob,addr,sex  having count(dob) > 1
```

For More http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_group_by_having.htm

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Sql is used to get data from a database which sometimes has a specific order. Further analysis of the received data is done in the tool you use to show the data. This can be a programming language or another tool that can use sql to receive data.